# Couldn't update or install using apt-get

Tags: linux, linux-mint, apt

My system is linux mint 16 - 64 bit
when I run `sudo apt-get update`, it ends with the following errors:

```
 Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/saucy-updates/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

When I try to run `sudo apt-get install apache2`, it gives the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apache2 : Depends: apache2-bin (= 2.4.6-2ubuntu2.2) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: apache2-data (= 2.4.6-2ubuntu2.2) but it is not going to be installed
 bluez-cups : Depends: cups
 language-pack-en-base : Depends: locales (>= 2.3.6) but it is not going to be installed
 language-pack-gnome-en-base : Depends: locales (>= 2.3.6) but it is not going to be installed
 lsb-cxx : Depends: lsb-core (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu4)
 lsb-graphics : Depends: lsb-core (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu4)
 lsb-languages : Depends: lsb-core (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu4)
 lsb-multimedia : Depends: lsb-core (>= 4.1+Debian11ubuntu4)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I run `sudo apt-get -f install`, it gives:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  alien at debugedit gcc-4.8-base:i386 lib32z1 libc6-i386 libgdict-1.0-6
  libgdict-common libgsoap3 libjpeg62 librpmbuild3 librpmsign1 libvncserver0
  lsb-security ncurses-term pax rpm
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  evince evince-common libevdocument3-4 libevview3-3
Suggested packages:
  nautilus apparmor
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bluez-cups language-pack-en language-pack-en-base language-pack-gnome-en
  language-pack-gnome-en-base lsb-cxx lsb-desktop lsb-graphics lsb-languages
  lsb-multimedia
The following packages will be upgraded:
  evince evince-common libevdocument3-4 libevview3-3
4 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 10 to remove and 14 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 904 kB of archives.
After this operation, 17.3 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  evince libevdocument3-4 libevview3-3 evince-common
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main evince amd64 3.10.0-0ubuntu2
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main libevdocument3-4 amd64 3.10.0-0ubuntu2
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main libevview3-3 amd64 3.10.0-0ubuntu2
  404  Not Found
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/main evince-common all 3.10.0-0ubuntu2
  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/evince/evince_3.10.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/evince/libevdocument3-4_3.10.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/evince/libevview3-3_3.10.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/e/evince/evince-common_3.10.0-0ubuntu2_all.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

My `sources.list` doesn't seem to be what it should be:

```
#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 16 _petra_ - Release amd64 20131126]/ saucy contrib main non-free
deb http://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org saucy main
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian vivid contrib
```

How do I correct my updates and installs? I suppose some problem arises because of the failure to reach the `archive.ubuntu.com/` server, but despite that case, can we do something?

Comment: Rule of thumb...whenever you get 404 on repos, always check EOL descriptors on the distro

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Saucy Salamander (13.10) went EOL in July 2014 as show [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).  You are getting the error because the files cannot be found (Error 404  on the end of your `apt-get update` output means file not found).

If you look at the repository at http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ you'll notice that `saucy` is not listed there - hence the 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you're still using Saucy? This version has been end of life since July 2014. If you still want to install packages from that release, you need to point your package sources to old-releases.ubuntu.com in sources.list.

However, I *strongly* recommend upgrading to an up-to-date release of Ubuntu. The current LTS version is 14.04 Trusty, the current non-LTS version is 15.10 Wily.

Here is a guide how to upgrade your EoL distribution to a current and supported release. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/

Comment: I have copy-pasted from a source list generator. Will this work for linux mint as well. How can I know the corresponding ubuntu version whose souce list will work for my linux mint distribution as well?

Comment: For Linux Mint the sources.list contains some extra repositories for Mint-specific stuff. Be careful not to delete those because you'd effectively be cross-grading to Ubuntu otherwise (which may break your system). For those change the release name (whatever it is) to "rosa" which is the name of Mint 17.3.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this despite all the warnings in the other answers, you can try opening up /etc/apt/sources.list and all text files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ with root rights and replace every mention of `LANGUAGECODE.archive.ubuntu.com` with `old-releases.ubuntu.com`.

Since you cannot find anything in sources.list, there should be something in sources.list.d I hope. (I do not use Linux Mint, so I cannot confirm.)